# Sound Design for the Electronic Musician & Absynth 5

Tags: synthesizer

I have Native Instrument's Absynth 5 and absolutely love this synthesizer program. I have learned a lot about being creative with synths mostly from this program.  I have been teaching myself how to create great sounds from scratch  by studying the patches already in the program.  However, I do not believe I am learning efficiently enough. So I came across this program at Berklee music online that uses Reason and Absynth 5. I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts or experiences to share regarding this course. I have not found any comprehensive tutorials. I have found some helpful forum discussions. But it would really help a lot to have thorough walkthru on Absynth 5. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [Absynth Users Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/absynth-users/) on Yahoo which is filled with useful info.

This [DVD](http://www.amazon.com/Native-Instruments-Absynth-Tutorial-DVD/dp/B000AZ8426) is fairly old, but I imagine it's also a useful resource...as Absynth 5 is just a build upon the features of 3 and not a new beast altogether.

Comment: @justin_pearson Thanks, Justin! Very helpful!